# Question regarding Emacs Rocks! Episode 13: multiple-cursors

Tags: multiple-cursors

I'm watching the great Emacs Rocks! Episode 13: multiple-cursors vide at youbube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNa3axo40qM

There are several places I'm not clear how the author did it. At 0:32: https://youtu.be/jNa3axo40qM?t=32, how the author quickly deletes strings from the underscore character to the end of the words?

At 0:39:https://youtu.be/jNa3axo40qM?t=39, how does the author quickly select the strings like `class="fruit"`? I guess it's a shortcuts from the html-mode but I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing what the author did. Heres what I use to achieve them :-

For the trick at 0:32, We can achieve this using `smartparens` package. Just enable `smartparens-mode` and press `C-k`. That's it.

As for the trick at 0:39, we can do this in two ways :-

1. Using `expand-region` package. Check [this](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) link for details on how to use this.
2. If you have `web-mode` installed, it has a command to select the attribute. It is bound to `C-c C-a s` by default.